# Communication link failure: 1047 WSREP has not yet prepared node for application use in

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, galera

We had a three-node cluster with MariaDB 10.4. We had an outage and the servers all rebooted with one having an irrecoverable network issue at the time.

We set up another server and added it to the cluster as a third member later.

However, ever since that, we have constantly been getting this error every now and then.

```
*3287799 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: An Error occurred while handling another error:
PDOException: SQLSTATE[08S01]: Communication link failure: 1047 WSREP has not yet prepared node for application use in /var/....yii2/db/Command.php:1293
```

In order to fix this issue, we turned down all three nodes one by one and then re-initialized the cluster, even with a new cluster name and all.

The first one was started with "galera_new_cluster" and the remaining two were added to this cluster. However, we still kept getting the same error intermittently.

The workaround at [mariadb galera - Error when a node shutdown ERROR 1047 WSREP has not yet prepared node for application use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40653238/mariadb-galera-error-when-a-node-shutdown-error-1047-wsrep-has-not-yet-prepare)  was followed but that didn't do anything, as expected.

Next, what we did is set up a single fresh server and installed the new 10.5.X MariaDB server on it. Took backup from the old cluster using mariabackup and restored it onto this new single server.

This single server was set up as a new cluster with fresh details and everything. We wanted to run it as a single node cluster to make sure if the error still persisted. Oddly enough, the error is still there and it comes off every half an hour or so.

Has anyone got any clue what could be the reason for this weird issue we're facing? Currently, we don't know what exactly is the issue which is why we're facing a hard time solving it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Update:
We turned off galera on this single-node cluster and ran it as a simple stand-alone mariadb server. However we still go the same errors in our web-server's logs. This is bonkers.

Any idea? Anyone?

Comment: were you able to solve it ?